# What missions do I have to play to collect all the Bobbleheads in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 3 you could only collect all of the Bobbleheads if you played through the main story line missions. For example the Energy Weapons Bobblehead was located at Raven Rock and only accessible after being kidnapped by the Enclave - which was near the end of the main storyline.

I'm planning my second Fallout 4 character and I don't want them to engage with the main story line after leaving Vault 111, but I do want them to collect all of the Bobbleheads.

Is this possible?

What missions do I have to play to collect all the Bobbleheads in Fallout 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have collected all of the Bobbleheads. Here are the missions I needed to play through to collect them:

**Strength bobblehead** - no missions

**Perception bobblehead** - start, but not finish [When Freedom Calls](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/When_Freedom_Calls)

**Endurance bobblehead** - no amissions

**Charisma bobblehead** - complete [Special Delivery](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Delivery) & [Emogene Takes A Lover](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Emogene_Takes_a_Lover) - start, but not finish [The Secret of Cabot House](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Secret_of_Cabot_House)

**Intelligence bobblehead** - no missions

**Agility bobblehead** - no missions

**Luck bobblehead** - no missions

**Barter bobblehead** - no missions

**Big guns bobblehead** - no missions

**Energy weapons bobblehead** - complete [Unlikely Valentine](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Unlikely_Valentine) & [Getting a Clue](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Getting_a_Clue) - start, but not finish [Reunions](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Reunions)

**Explosives bobblehead** - no missions

**Lock picking bobblehead** - no missions

**Medicine bobblehead** - start, but not finish [Hole in the Wall](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Hole_in_the_Wall)

**Melee bobblehead** - start, but not finish [Curtain Call](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Curtain_Call)

**Repair bobblehead** - no missions

**Science bobblehead** - start, but not finish [Vault 75](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_75_(quest))

**Small guns bobblehead** - no missions

**Sneak bobblehead** - no missions

**Speech bobblehead** - start, but not finish [Unlikely Valentine](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Unlikely_Valentine)

**Unarmed bobblehead** - no missions

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the [bobblehead's location](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_bobblehead#Fallout_4), you can see that all of them are located inside freely accessible buildings or areas, except four:

- The Perception Bobblehead is located in the Museum of Freedom, and is accessible during the quest "When Freedom Calls", which is the third quest in the main storyline
- The Charisma Bobblehead is inside Parsons State Insane Asylum, which
  can only be accessed when you start the side quest "The Secret of Cabot House".
- The Speech Bobblehead is inside a vault, in the room you find a new companion during the quest "Unlikely Valentine", the fifth quest of Act 1. The room can only be accessed by killing a named NPC guarding the door, so is not available otherwise.
- The Energy Weapon Bobblehead is inside Fort Hagen. Sadly, it is located in a part that is only accessible through an elevator that is activated only by starting the quest "Getting a Clue", the sixth quest in Act 1.

So in order to get all bobbleheads, you would need to go through the main storyline up to the sixth quest and complete the non-affiliated quest from Cabot. You would still be in Act 1, but the main story line would be *pretty much* engaged.

Comment: If you have a jetpack mod on a power armor torso, you can reach the roof where perception bobblehead is, but I do not know if you can grab the minigun off of the vertibird from the front. If you can, then I expect that you can get the bobblehead without activating the quest. (untested by me obviously)

Comment: @Yorik The bobblehead is in the locked room where Preston and other settlers are, not on the roof.

Comment: When Freedom Calls is not a main quest. You can finish the game without doing that.

Comment: @DCShannon Yes, you can skip that quest and head to Diamond City directly and complete it later. But it does not change its status of main quest, the third one of Act 1.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault No, you don't have to go complete it later. You can just not do it. It's a side quest.

Comment: @DCShannon You don't _have_ to, but it still does not change its status of [third main quest from Act 1](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_quests).

Comment: I thought about this some more last night, and I'm not sure what to call "When Freedom Calls". The branching nature of FO4's storyline makes things more complex. It's required if you want to finish with the minutemen, so it would be a main quest in that case, but it's optional if you do any other faction, in which case it's a side quest. There's no such thing as "Acts". That's just a classification somebody put together for convenience.

Comment: Thank you. While you start When Freedom Calls to get the Perception Bobblehead you don't have to complete it.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect that you must play through the story missions in order to get all of the bobbleheads.

This is demonstrated early on when you first meet the Minutemen in Concord, the door on the top floor of the Museum of Freedom is locked, and in the room behind that door is a perception bobblehead. This is the room in which you first meet the Minutemen and in order for them to unlock the door for you to get into the room you must clear out all of the raiders in the building.

Comment: The top floor *is* reachable using a jetpack, but not having tried this I am not sure if the minigun is removable from the front...

Comment: -1 because this is just a guess ("I expect") and the only example isn't even a main quest.

Comment: The only example is a story mission, though - it introduces you to one of the key factions in the game and the answer is clearly not "incorrect" due to the energy weapons bobblehead inside Fort Hagen...